# SSL with Virtual Hosts on Apache in Amazon AWS EC2 environment

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I am trying to set up two virtual hosts served over SSL on Apache in Amazon AWS environment.

I understand that SSL cannot use Name Virtual Host on Apache unless:
* I bind two IPs to Apache each serving a separate virtual host. Unfortunately, AWS does not allow me to bind more than one public IP to each EC2 machine
* or I use SNI (server name identification) which does not work for IE6 or WinXP (all browsers).

Is my understanding correct?

If yes, what are my options on AWS where I cannot bind two IPs and if I want to server my site to WinXP and IE6?

The only thing I can think of setting up two new micro instances with proxy servers each serving each instance and the forwarding to the actual server.

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using UCC for several sites using one IP.

See also this thread:
[SSL on a single server for multiple web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883058/ssl-on-a-single-server-for-multiple-web-sites)